# Changing the max upload size for the Joomla jDownloads component

Tags: components, joomla1.5

How do I change the max upload size in the jDownloads component in Joomla?. I changed it, but it didn't change after saving.

Comment: I think you have to add this to php.ini: upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

Comment: or this to .htaccesss: php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

Answer (score 0):

You also have to change the `php.ini` file. `upload_max_filesize = 2M` is the default - you have to change this value to another value.